# How to make a button that outputs an integer in a text widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't have any idea how to make a buttons that output an integer.

This is a cash register system, everytime the user click that button the price should automatically sums up in the total, and automatically minus and show up a change.

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.font import Font

class MainUI:
    def __init__(self,master):

        #MAIN WINDOW
        self.mainFrame = Frame(master, width=800, height=600, 
        bg="skyblue")
        master.title("FCPC CASH REGISTER")
        self.mainFrame.pack()
        self.title = Label(self.mainFrame, text="FIRST CITY PROVIDENTIAL" 
        " COLLEGE", bg="blue")
        self.font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=29)
        self.title.configure(font=self.font)
        self.title.place(x=50, y=50)

        #BUTTONS
        self.snacksButton = Button(self.mainFrame, text="SNACKS", 
        command=self.snackList, width=10, bg="blue")
        self.font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=20)
        self.snacksButton.configure(font=self.font)
        self.snacksButton.place(x=100,y=150,)


        #TOTAL
        self.total = Label(self.mainFrame,text="TOTAL:", 
        bg="blue",width=8)
        self.total.place(x=370,y=160)
        self.font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=25)
        self.total.configure(font=self.font)

        #CHANGE
        self.change = Label(self.mainFrame,text="CHANGE:", bg="blue")
        self.change.place(x=370,y=240)
        self.font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=25)
        self.change.configure(font=self.font)




    def snackList(self):
        self.frame = Toplevel(width=800,height=600,bg="skyblue")
        self.frame.title("SNACKS")

        self.novaButton = Button(self.frame, text="NOVA(12php)", 
        command=self.calculate ,width=15, bg="blue")
        self.font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=15)
        self.novaButton.configure(font=self.font)
        self.novaButton.place(x=100,y=150)



root = Tk()
ui = MainUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I want the button to output the price and automatically calculates the total amount.

Comment: Please share a sample of what you expect?

Comment: its not really clear what you're asking to me

Comment: if user clicks a button(for example: piatosButton) the price of the selected item will output in the Label(which is Total) and if the user clicks another button it will automatically sums up the price

Comment: Im sorry if  I did not specify it clearly

Comment: You need to update your code because there are variables used twice.  For example, `self.total` is used as `StringVar` and `Label`.

Comment: Part 1: To update "Total", call a common function for all your buttons(like piatos) and pass the button widget itself as argument to it. In that function, get the price of button using  the text of that button, check the current value of Total label, add them and update text of total.
Part 2: To update "Change" label, assign a `IntVar()` variable as textvariable to your Entry widget. Create a trace function for that variable, which will be called everytime user types in the Entry box. Calculate the change there and update the label if required.

Comment: Also don't forget to use unique variable names as suggested by @acw1668. `self.total`, `self.change` and `self.entry` are reused in your code.

Comment: aight, thanks for the answer

Comment: Please reduce the code down to a [mcve]. For example, if the problem is with a button and a text widget, we don't need more than one button or a bunch of functions that create new windows.

Comment: aight, im sorry

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a simple example to illustrate what you might need to do. Associate each button to a function that adds the price of a snack to the total amount and changes what is displayed. One way to do it is with a textvariable option of tkinter Label widget.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk


def calculate(price):
    global total, var
    total += price
    text = 'Total = ' + str(total)
    var.set(text)


root = tk.Tk()

total = 0
var = tk.StringVar()

button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Snickers 1$', command=lambda: calculate(price=1)).pack()
button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Mars 2$', command=lambda: calculate(price=2)).pack()
totalLabel = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for the answer!, i tried another one, but this is better and made my code less